# How can I access non-contiguous content of a range variable without using arrays

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

RE-RECLARIFIED: I am a excel vba newbie, so bear with me...

I need to access a single cell in a non-contiguous range variable and alter its value.

Is there no sequential way to loop through a non-contiguous range variable?

For example:

```
rng = Range("d1:d6, d12")
```

There are 7 cells in this range but I can't loop through the cells  in this range because the "cells" function sees the 7th cell as d7. Or can I in some other way?

I can't use FOR EACH because I need to use another variable other than the range itself to jump through range and change values in it.

So here is a non-functioning example of what I'm looking to do:

```
' If I could access a range like an array

    rng(1) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter customer's name: ", Title:="CUSTOMER NAME", Type:=2)
    rng(2) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter travel out date: ", Title:="TRAVEL OUT DATE", Type:=1)
    rng(3) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter travel back date: ", Title:="TRAVEL BACK DATE", Type:=1)
    rng(4) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter number of technicians: ", Title:="TECHNICIANS", Type:=1)
    rng(5) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter number of engineers: ", Title:="ENGINEERS", Type:=1)
    rng(6) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter location: ", Title:="LOCATION", Type:=2)
    rng(7) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter todays date: ", Title:="TODAY'S DATE", Type:=1)
```

I don't want to use an array because I don't just want to manipulate the values of the cells separately, I want to alter the value in the cell and have it reflected in that cell without having to go through the process of reloading the array contents into the range, which presents me with the same issue again anyway.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah. I didn't make myself clear (rookie mistake). I need to be able to access that seventh cell using it's location in the range, not it's value (right now I seem to only be able to access it using the location rng.cells(12,1)). Basically I need to be able access that non-contiguous cell like I would in an array without making it an array because when I change it I want it to change the value in the cell.

Comment: More clarification.... I need to create a loop based on another value that is not related to the range, access those cells in the range and change them without having to switch the range out to an array and back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, how about this?

```
Sub test()

  Dim Arr() As String         ' dynamic array,
  ReDim Arr(Selection.Count)  ' ... properly sized
  i = 0
  For Each c In Selection
    i = i + 1
    Arr(i) = c.Address        ' save each cell address
  Next c

  ' now we can reference the cells sequentially
  Range(Arr(1)) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter customer's name: ", Title:="CUSTOMER NAME", Type:=2)
  Range(Arr(2)) = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter travel out date: ", Title:="TRAVEL OUT DATE", Type:=1)
' ...

End Sub
```

Comment: AH YES! Let my noobiness shine. While this is not exactly what I'm looking for, it makes the point that the answer is not to expect a range to act like an array, not to make the range an array, BUT to make the referenced cells in the range an array, that way I can reassign the array whenever I want without have to re-write every range reference and I can call for a cell by it's array position whenever I need to. SORRY to everyone for my horrifically opaque inquiry, and thank you Alan.

Answer (score 1):

If you highlight the cells you want to access on the spreadsheet itself, you can do this:

```
Sub accessAll()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        (do something here)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This takes each cell that you've highlighted and does something to it.

Comment: +1: or without selecting cells just use `Range("d1:d6, d12")` instead of `Selection`

Comment: Ah. I didn't make myself clear (rookie mistake). I need to be able to access that seventh cell using it's location in the range, not it's value (right now I seem to only be able to access it using the location rng.cells(12,1)). Basically I need to be able access that non-contiguous cell like I would in an array without making it an array because when I change it I want it to change the value in the cell.

Comment: More clarification.... I need to create a loop based on another value that is not related to the range, access those cells in the range and change them without having to switch the range out to an array and back again.

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, I don't really know what you want at this point.

Comment: OK. Let me try this...  See me RE-RECLARIFICATION above

Comment: I think that would be true if the each question were the same. Then I could loop through FOR EACH. The reason I don't want to use the specific range reference is because the definition of the range may change in the future but the number of cells, and their configuration of values, won't.

Answer (score 0):

Non-regular or non-contiguous ranges have `Areas` representing regular rectangular sub-ranges.
EDIT: note that two Areas may overlap, so watch out for this if using the code below...

```
Dim a as range, c as range

For each a in yourRange.Areas
    For each c in a
      'something with c
    Next c
Next a
```

EDIT: you can use a function to get the n'th cell from your range.

Note this will return Nothing if you ask for an index beyond the range's size.

```
'get the n'th cell from a non-contiguous range
'probably not efficient for large ranges...
Function NthCell(rng as Range, n as integer) as Range
    Dim i as integer, c as Range
    Dim rv as Range

    i=1
    for each c in rng.Cells
        if i=n then
            Set rv=c
            Exit For
        end if
    Next c

    Set NthCell=rv
End Function


'Sample usage:
Set rng = Range("D1:D6,D12")
NthCell(rng, 1).Value = ....
NthCell(rng, 7).Value = ....
```

Comment: This is excellent as well and expands on the point above. Thank you so much for the help.